# Starting a new intent with FragmentsActivity - crashes

Tags: java, android, android-intent, crash, android-fragmentactivity

This is my first question and i already searched for an answer, but i couldn't find one.
My App starts with an SplashScreen Video and after the Video is done the Activity tries to start my MainActivity wich extends FragmentActivity. But the App crashes with following Log:

```
05-17 11:32:56.554: W/Binder(476): Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
05-17 11:32:56.554: W/Binder(476): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-17 11:32:56.554: W/Binder(476):  at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
05-17 11:32:56.554: W/Binder(476):  at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
05-17 11:32:56.554: W/Binder(476):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
05-17 11:32:56.554: W/Binder(476):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
05-17 11:32:56.554: W/InputMethodManagerService(360): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 1075 uid 10052
05-17 11:32:56.574: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(514): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

Here is What my SplashScreen class looks like:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
    // Splash screen timer
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 6000;
    public void Skip(View v) {
        SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.intro);
        String uriPath = "android.resource://de.ebs_hannover.sean.elsaapp/"+R.raw.intro_vid;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        mVideoView.start();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

And This is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    ViewPager viewPager=null;
    TextView cPosTxt =null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        cPosTxt =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cPosTxt);
        viewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                if(arg0==0) {
                    cPosTxt.setText(R.string.menue);
                }
                if (arg0==1) {
                    cPosTxt.setText(R.string.btn_jubi);
                }
                if (arg0==2) {
                    cPosTxt.setText(R.string.btn_info);
                } 
                if (arg0==3) {
                    cPosTxt.setText(R.string.btn_story);
                } 
                if (arg0==4) {
                    cPosTxt.setText(R.string.btn_events);
                }
                if (arg0==5) {
                    cPosTxt.setText(R.string.btn_current);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }
    public void StroemClick(View v) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
    }
    public void JubiClick(View v) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
    }
    public void InfoClick(View v) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(2, true);
    }
    public void StoryClick(View v) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(3, true);
    }
    public void EventsClick(View v) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(4, true);
    }
    public void CurrentClick(View v) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(5, true);
    }
}
class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        Fragment fragment=null;
        if(arg0==0){
            fragment=new MenuFragment();
        }
        if(arg0==1) {
            fragment=new JubiFragment();
        }
        if(arg0==2) {
            fragment=new InfoFragment();
        }
        if(arg0==3){
            fragment=new StoryFragment();
        }
        if(arg0==4){
            fragment=new EventsFragment();
        }
        if(arg0==5){
            fragment=new CurrentFragment();
        }
        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 6;
    }
}
```

And just in case (because i have the suggestion that this might be the problem) here is my Manifest aswell:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.ebs_hannover.sean.elsaapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name="de.ebs_hannover.sean.elsaapp.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

What am i doing wrong? Without the SplashScreen at the begining it works fine... So When i set my MainActivity to the Launcher Activity in the Manifest... Thanks for any help :)

Comment: post your full stacktrace..

Comment: Well... I feel very dump right now :D it was really just that simple... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the `MainActivity` Class inside your `<application>` tag:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity
        android:name="de.ebs_hannover.sean.elsaapp.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    // ADD ALL ACTIVITIES LIKE THIS:
    <activity
        android:name="de.ebs_hannover.sean.elsaapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
</application>
```